# Growth of the condition number of Hilbert matrices

Tags: condition-number, hilbert-matrices

Hilbert matrices are well known to be ill-conditioned, with the columns being almost linearly dependent.
On the wikipedia page, they state that the condition number grows as $$O((1+\sqrt{2})^{4n}/\sqrt{n}$$
I think the corresponding reference for this statement is the paper "The Condition Number of the Finite Segment of the Hilbert Matrix", by John Todd, but I couldn't manage to find a copy of it.
I would really like to know what kind of tools one can use to proof a result like this one. Does anyone know this proof or at least can give a sketch ?

Since this proof might be involved, I'm also interested in any proof of a weaker lower bound that one can prove using "basic" tools.

Thanks!

Comment: Yes, that's old like dirt, there's no real need that you check the proof, it's ok. It was checked and re-checked in the last millenium. And how much simpler than $O(A^n/\sqrt{n})$ do you want it to be?!

Comment: I don't want to check the proof, I just want to know what kind of tools one can use to prove a result like this. And by "simpler lower bound", I mean a one that might be easier to prove if this one use involved tools. I'm editing to make this more clear.

Comment: Well, since the inverse matrix can be computed explicitly, where's the problem? ;-) Just kidding. I've computed the condition of calculating orthogonal polynomials from those moments (the entries of the Hilbert matrix are the moments of Lebesgue measure on $[0,1]$), once, and it's the same order of magnitude.